# How to run Emacs from terminal as nonlocking window on Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, macos-high-sierra

I taped 'emacs' in the terminal on Mac (High Sierra) and pressed return.
As a result, I have a new Emacs window.
Everything okay, but I can't continue to use terminal because it looks like locked by this emacs window.

How can I use terminal and Emacs in parallel independently?

Comment: Do you just want to start Emacs from a terminal in the background?  With most shells, you just append a `&`, e.g. `emacs &`.  You can also stop a process with `C-z` in the shell, and use job control commands `fg` and `bg` to continue the process in the foreground or background.

Comment: 'emacs &' is the solution to my problem. Thanks. Can you answer this as an answer (not comment) to give me the ability to accept it?

Comment: 'emacs &' exists in the existing answer. I accepted it. My previous comment isn't actual. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to start emacs from the terminal or run emacs within the terminal?  The two are very different.  To start emacs from the terminal, the conventional wisdom is to [use `emacsclient`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) to send a GUI emacs instructions to open a given file.

If you want to run emacs within a terminal while maintaining access to your terminal, you have a few options:

- Use a multiplexer like `tmux`
- Run a terminal emulator within emacs (I like plain ole' `M-x term`, but there are fancier ones)

---

If you're just talking about throwing the process into the background, use `C-z` (i.e., `M-x suspend-frame`) from a running emacs.  If you want to *start* emacs in the background, do it like any other job using `&`.  I'll refer you to your shell's documentation for job management.  ([Here's one for Bash.](//tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html))

Comment: I needed to run emacs from terminal as background window.

Comment: See edit. I added another option beside `&` (which I'd forgotten isn't common knowledge)